# Is there any difference among exoplanets in composition due to host star?

Tags: star, planet, exoplanet, astrochemistry

Simply put, would, say, rocky planets orbiting red dwarfs have a noticably different chemical makeup than rocky planets orbiting B-type main sequence stars? *Mutatis mutandis* gas giants and the other types of host stars.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The chemical makeup of space dust -- the stuff  which agglomerates into planets -- is dependent on the history of supernovas and neutron stars and the like which created the atoms in a given region of space.  This is unlikely to bear any relationship to the size or age of the star around which said items revolve.

Comment: Then it is as I suspected: Master of Orion has it wrong

Comment: Someone should make a space 4X game with realistic star systems